Auditing Gmail Activity in Google Workspace
I'm working on a project that involves ingesting Audit Logs/Activity Events from Google Workspace. It appears to be pretty straightforward to pull most relevant data using the Reports API, but there's a limitation I need to workaround.
The list of applications the Reports API allows you to pull Audit Logs/Activity Events for does not include Gmail. I tried also checking the Gmail API, but I can't seem to find a way to pull Gmail Audit Logs/Activity Events using either API.
Does anyone know how I can pull Audit Log activity programatically from Google Workspace? The events I want to ingest appear in the Admin Console UI during a search, but don't seem to be available in any of the APIs and I feel like I'm missing something.
How can I pull Gmail Audit Logs from Google Workspace?
Thanks for your time.
